# Display XML with ASP.NET on a Web Page

Tags: html, asp.net, xml, razor, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to ASP.NET and started creating a website with basic razor syntax.
I'm trying to display a grid with tile-like div elements from a XML file show below.
So far I haven't found anything that would work for this.

"/content/content.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<categories>
  <home>
    <tile text="Title 1"></tile>
    <tile text="Title 2"></tile>
  </home>
</categories>
```

"/home.cshtml"

```
<body>
    @{ razor code or something}
    <div id="page">
        <div id="categories"></div>
        <div id="tiles"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would like to get the content from the xml file and display it in html like show:

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="categories">Home</div>
        <div id="tiles">
            <div>Title 1</div>
            <div>Title 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note: this is a simplified version of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) transformation to create the desired output from the specific input. Then I would render the specific output as if it was being a string.

Hope I helped!

Comment: I never heard of XSLT, thanks. Though I would still like to know how to get the data from another page like the php include function. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Glad to help. The `include` question is another question. Perhaps you should check [master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX). Anyway, you should upvote the answer. It is very important for users navigating to your question to identify useful answers. Anyway,